# .htaccess subdirectory redirect with non www to www and parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /qsg/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?Item=$1 [L]
</IfModule>



<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /qsg/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?Item=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I tried to look for an answer, but haven't been able to find one.

I am trying to redirect:
http://example.com/qsg/abcd
to
http://www.example.com/qsg/index.php?Item=abcd

I can get this working fine when the www is present in the URI. When I remove the www, it redirects to http://www.example.com/404.shtml

I've tried the two methods above with both the same result. I just can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I've seen plenty of other examples where this should work, but not for me. Do I have something wrong in my .htaccess file is there a possibility of something else causing the bad redirect?

Note: both the above rewrites are not included in the file. I've tried both independently.

Answer (score 0):

Give this one a shot:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteBase /qsg/

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?Item=$1 [L,PT]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This is still sending me to the http://www.example.com/404.shtml
Is there a possibility something else maybe causing this?

Comment: if there is it would be htaccess conflicts... I'm tryin to figure it out, it works just fine on my end which is weird.

Comment: I thought it might be another htaccess conflict. However, I checked the main htaccess file in the root directory and there doesn't seem to be anything that stands out.

Comment: add the www part to the main htaccess